# Script to run C++ code with different user input

Tags: shell

I have a c++ executable file 'Score' that takes as input two user defined 'values'.
These values are some data in txt files. I run the program and save the output to a text file like this :

```
./Score data1.txt data2.txt >outdata1data2.txt
```

Because I need to run this for many times would be possible to create a shell bash script that does this automatically something like :

```
./Score data1.txt data3.txt >outdata1data3.txt
./Score data1.txt data4.txt >outdata1data4.txt
```

and so on..

The names of the data are all different and all in the same directory as the executable file.
My knowledge in C++ is very limited and any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you [edit] your question to specify which shell type? bash? other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely possible.
You will probably want to write a shell script similar to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename1 in /*.txt; do
  for filename2 in /*.txt; do
    ./Score "$filename1" "$filename1" > "out$filename1$filename2"
  done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

for dataFile in data*.txt; do
    # Ignore data1.txt.
    [[ $dataFile == data1.txt ]] && continue

    ./Score data1.dxt "$dataFile" > "outdata1$dataFile"
done
```

This loops over files named `data*.txt` in the current directory. Since that matches `data1.txt`, it needs to be explicitly ignored. It then calls `./Score` with each matching file name and names the output file based on the input file.